# cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int' for argument '2' to 'std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to get the minimum value in by alphabetical order.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void swap(string[], int i, int j);
string displayArray(string[], int size);
string findMin(string[] , int size);

int main()
{
    string themin;
    int size;
    string A[7] = { "MBA", "ME", "Psy", "EE", "CS", "CE", "Bio" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    swap(A, 1, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    findMin(A, themin);
    cout<< themin << endl;

}

void swap(string A[], int i, int j)
{
    string temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}

string findMin(string A[] , int size)
{
    string themin = A[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i ++)
    {
        if(A[i].compare(themin) < 0)
            themin=A[i];
    }
    return themin;
}
```

I receive this error, but do not understand how to fix it:

> 25:26: error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int' for argument '2' to 'std::string findMin(std::string*, int)'

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You are passing a `std::string` where an `int` is expected. You are passing the `themin` variable (a `string`) to the `size` parameter (an `int`). And you are not even assigning any value to `themin` before passing it (or the `size` variable, for that matter). This code is a mix of gibberish, what are you trying to accomplish with it exactly?

Comment: Because you're passing a string where an int is expected? Your function `findMin(...)` accepts a string array and an int. you've put a string array and then a string

Comment: How can I fix this? This is what the teacher wrote and gave the class. I have to find the minimum value using alphabetical order.

Comment: Assuming your task was not to resolve their nonsense code, simply contact them and tell them their code doesn't build.

Comment: Use STL: [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) + [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) + [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) = done!

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two lines:

```
findMin(A, themin);
cout<< themin << endl;
```

with:

```
themin = findMin(A, sizeof A / sizeof A[0]);
cout << endl << themin << endl;
```